# Openstack kolla FWaaS Zed setup

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I have set up OpenStack with Kolla-Ansible Zed. However, I noticed that there is no `enable_plugin` option in the `/etc/kolla/global.yml` file. Now, I am trying to install FWaaS (Firewall-as-a-Service) following the instructions provided in this OpenStack's [Firewall-as-a-Service (FWaaS) v2 scenario](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/zed/admin/fwaas-v2-scenario.html) documentation.

The documentation states, On Ubuntu and CentOS, modify the `[fwaas]` section in the `/etc/neutron/fwaas_driver.ini` file instead of `/etc/neutron/neutron.conf`. Unfortunately, I cannot find the `fwaas_driver.ini` file in the `neutron-server`, `neutron-l3-agent`, or `neutron-openvswitch-agent` containers. Furthermore, when following the steps in the documentation, the Firewall group status doesn't change to `ACTIVE`.

I came across this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/neutron/+bug/2009705) which seems to address the same issue.

However, I believe I might be missing something. Can someone guide me on how to properly install FWaaS in a Kolla environment using the information from the provided link? Additionally, the documentation does not specify which `pip` and `apt` packages needs to be installed for `FWaaS`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have found the solution for this issue.?

I also want to enable fwaas in openstack release 2023.1 antelope deployed through kolla-ansible and couldn't find fwaas_driver.ini after following the guide Firewall-as-a-Service (FWaaS) v2 scenario.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/565579)